# Get demographic info from audience insight group from Facebook marketing API

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-marketing-api, audience

I'm trying to get demographic audience data from the Facebook Marketing API.

If I do this search I only get audience size:-

6003024075156?fields=audience_size,description,name,topic,disambiguation_category

which returns

```
{
  "audience_size": 2824330,
  "description": null,
  "name": "Air New Zealand",
  "topic": "Business and industry",
  "disambiguation_category": "Airline Company",
  "id": "6003024075156"
}
```

In the documentation it suggests I can get other info as seen in the main audience insights panel in Business Manager

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/audience-insights-query/

I'm particularly interested in knowing how to construct the query to return the demographic info of the audience

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/audience-insights-age-gender/

```
Field   Description
age_by_gender
list<AudienceInsightsAgeGender>
Demographic information by gender
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I've been working on a similar problem *all day* and have gotten nowhere. If you ever find the solution, will you post it here please? Thanks, and good luck!

Comment: Did you guys ever figured this out?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want should be here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/audiences-api/audience-insights-api/v2.8

However, the lock icon beside it suggests to me that no such API exists. This is probably due to the fact that Facebook uses a third party (http://www.acxiom.com/) to acquire the aggregate demographic data.